# How to access Unix Domain Sockets from the command line?

Tags: linux, unix, curl, unix-socket

Reading a Unix Domain Socket file using Python is similar to an ordinary TCP socket:

```python
>>> import socket
>>> import sys
>>>
>>> server_address = '/tmp/tbsocket1'  # Analogous to TCP (address, port) pair
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.connect(server_address)
>>> sock.recv(512)
'*** uWSGI Python tracebacker output ***\n\n'
```

Since UDS are not ordinary files, `cat` does not work on them:

```
$ sudo cat /tmp/tbsocket1
cat: /tmp/tbsocket1: No such device or address
```

Neither do `curl`:

```
$ sudo curl /tmp/tbsocket1
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

**How do I read or write to Unix Domain Sockets using standard command line tools like curl?**

PS: In a strange coincidence, a [curl patch was suggested very recently](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2014-11/0384.html))

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `ncat` command from the `nmap` project:

```
ncat -U /tmp/tbsocket1
```

To make it easy to access, you can do this:

```
# forward incoming 8080/tcp to unix socket
ncat -vlk 8080 -c 'ncat -U /tmp/tbsocket1'
# make a http request via curl
curl http://localhost:8080
```

---

You can also use `socat`:

```
# forward incoming 8080/tcp to unix socket
socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork UNIX:/tmp/tbsocket1
```

Comment: I tried using this. But i get error: "invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096) skip.." on application log. Is it possible to use it for: uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/web2py.socket;

Answer (score 9):

`nc -U </unix/socket>` almost in any Linux, BSD, MacOs.

Comment: Yp, not the netcat-traditional on Debian. I had to switch to netcat-openbsd which has support for unix sockets. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/how-can-i-communicate-with-a-unix-domain-socket-via-the-shell-on-debian-squeeze

Answer (score 0):

Forward incoming 8080/tcp to unix socket using `socat`:

NB: A process must be listening on `/tmp/tbsocket1`

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/tbsocket1 TCP-LISTEN:8080 & 
curl http://localhost:8080
```